# Show spinner while porcessing in GWT

Tags: gwt, mouseevent, spinner

I'd like to know if possible to show a spinner while the application is making some calculations.

I'm using a slider bar to modify an svg image. I call the function which makes the calculations to modify the svg image when the MouseUp event is fired. Now, since the image is made of a lot of svg paths, it takes a while (around 1s) until the svg image is updated; here's where I want to show the spinner, to let the user know the application is processing data. Btw, when I say "updating the svg image" I'm actually deleting the current svg paths and creting/adding new paths to the DOM.

I created a widget to show the spinner, it extends the class `PopupPanel`. I read that to handle a widget, it has to be added to the DOM first, so I'm creating and hiding that widget in the View's constructor (I'm using MVP), so when the application is processing I just would need to call the function show().

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

If you can chunk your 1s of processing into 20 pieces of 0.05s work, then you can absolutely achieve this.  Algorithm!

1: Display your spinning progress graphic in a popup

2: Use `Scheduler.scheduleDeferred` to schedule the first/next 0.05s of work

3: At the end of the deferred code, go to step 2 and schedule the next chunk of work

4: When all work is done, hide the spinning progress graphic!

By scheduling the work in small chunks, you give the browser a chance to do its other tasks - animate the spinner, receive input, etc.  If you just make a big loop that takes 1s to execute, none of those other things can happen in the meantime.